# How to use the "UserComments" schema item?

Tags: html, microdata, schema.org

Let's say I have the mark-up like this:

```
<ul id="comments">

  <li class="comment"> 
    <div class="author">on Friday 3th, Jenny said:</div>
    <div class="content"><p>bla bla</p></div> 
  </li>

  <li class="comment"> 
    <div class="author">on Friday 3th, Jenny said:</div>
    <div class="content"><p>bla bla</p></div> 

    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="comment"> 
        <div class="author">on Friday 3th, Mary said:</div>
        <div class="content">stfu jenny</div> 
      </li>       
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
```

How do I use the "UserComments" item on this mark-up ? 
http://schema.org/UserComments

Where do I add `itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments"` ? Once on the list container, or multiple times on each list item?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/microdata.html#typed-items) typed items specs, you would add it to the container of your comments section, e.g.

```
<section itemscope itemtype="http://example.org/animals#cat">
 <h1 itemprop="name">Hedral</h1>
 <p itemprop="desc">Hedral is a male american domestic
 shorthair, with a fluffy black fur with white paws and belly.</p>
 <img itemprop="img" src="hedral.jpeg" alt="" title="Hedral, age 18 months">
</section>
```

So the item scope for your comment section would be formatted like this (taking into account the item properties):

```
<ul id="comments" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">

  <li class="comment"> 
    <div itemprop="name" class="author"><span itemprop="commentTime">on Friday 3th</span>, Jenny said:</div>
    <div itemprop="commentText" class="content"><p>bla bla</p></div> 
  </li>

  <li class="comment"> 
    <div itemprop="name" class="author"><span itemprop="commentTime">on Friday 3th</span>, Jenny said:</div>
    <div itemprop="commentText" class="content"><p>bla bla</p></div> 

    <ul class="level-2">
      <li class="comment"> 
        <div itemprop="name" class="author"><span itemprop="commentTime">on Friday 3th</span>, Mary said:</div>
        <div itemprop="commentText" class="content">stfu jenny</div> 
      </li>       
    </ul>
  </li>
...
```

Comment: As mattrepublic said below, an author is tagged using the "creator" property, not "name" doc says: _This is the same as the Author property for CreativeWork_. 
Plus, it's always better to use appropriate tags, when possible, so in this case, <time> for dates. `<time datetime="2013-11-03" itemprop="commentTime">Friday 3th</time>`

Comment: This is **not correct**. Each comment needs to be an own/separate item. In your code, there would only be *one comment* with several different names/times/texts.

Answer (score 8):

You shouldn't be using itemprop="name", but instead use "creator".

More examples... http://homebiss.blogspot.com/2011/11/schema-markups-blogger-comments.html

Answer (score 7):

Each comment would be an own item (UserComments in your example). You might also want to use an `article` element for each comment.

```
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/UserComments">
  <header>
    on 
    <time itemprop="commentTime" datetime="…">Friday 3th</time>, 
    <span itemprop="creator" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
      <span itemprop="name">Jenny</span>
    </span> 
    said:
  </header>
  <p itemprop="commentText">bla bla</p>
</article>
```

However, now there is also [Comment](http://schema.org/Comment), which seems to be more appropriate because it’s a CreativeWork (and not an Event, like UserComments).

Answer (score 0):

Due to [schema.org](https://schema.org/UserComments), It is good to change using [userComments](https://schema.org/UserComments) to [Comment](https://schema.org/UserComments):

> UserInteraction and its subtypes is an old way of talking about users interacting with pages. It is generally better to use Action-based vocabulary, alongside types such as Comment.

But you can use this item by adding `commentText` property and `creator` as a person to it.